# How can you store information from a loop into arrays and merge them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, concatenation

I'm trying to write a function that validates a card number based on Luhm algorithm. I managed to reach to the phase that I get the doubled numbers and the rest of the numbers and I want to store them into arrays so I can do a sum of these. The code that I have stores each of the numbers in arrays but when I try to do `.concat` on the array and `console.log` it I get an empty array. And I believe that the numbers should be stored in the memory. I want to run a `.reduce` on the combined array so I can get the sum. This is a visualization of what I'm trying to do: [Codecademy SVG](https://codecademy-content.s3.amazonaws.com/PRO/independent-practice-projects/credit-card-checker/diagrams/cc+validator+diagram+1.svg)

```
const validateCard = (card) => {
  let nDigits = card.length;
  let firstArray = [];
  let secondArray = [];
  const numbers = firstArray.concat(secondArray);
  for (let i = nDigits - 1, x = nDigits - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2, x -= 2) {
    let doubledNumber = card[x] * 2;
    if (doubledNumber> 9) {
      doubledNumber-= 9;
    }
    firstArray.push(card[i]);
    secondArray.push(doubledNumber);
  }
};
```

Comment: Just move the definition of `numbers` after the loop.

Comment: Uh, you initialize `firstArray` and `secondArray` to empty arrays, and then you concat them.  Why wouldn't they be empty?

Comment: firstSecondArray.push({first: card[i], second: doubleNumber})

Comment: @Aplet123 The hell with that, so I did everything right except that. Still if I pushed each number that I get from the loop into the arrays. Shouldn't that allow me to place const numbers under the arrays and not under the loop ?

Comment: concat after the loop

Comment: I got the answer from @Aplet123, I just had to define the combined array after the loop. Thanks budd